# Vivid pictures knock joy upon lunatics

Tags: steganography

> Here you are.
>   Standing in front of the dawn.
>   Multiply zebras by wicked Queen Xylophia.
>   Grand November rain causing eruption.
>   Vivid pictures knock joy upon lunatics.

What is hidden inside this message?

Comment: Any hints? I'm stumped

Comment: It's only been here an hour...

Comment: Wow this is really tricky!

Comment: I must say, there wasn't an actual message in the puzzle. Question was inappropriate. Yet, there are smarter people in the world. Good Job @Luciferangel

Comment: @RahulParashar the question never said there was a message, it just asked **what** was hidden inside the message. Plus if you're referring to the clues, you can't really say something isn't a message

Comment: @Areeb The tag wiki for [tag:steganography] says "Hidden messages concealed in...", which is somewhat misleading. I think the tag was inappropriate.

Comment: @Ankoganit, what should the tag be then? Practically, the technique to reach the answer is the same. But maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Not really sure... [tag:letters] or [tag:lateral-thinking] maybe?

Comment: @Ankoganit I just asked about this on Meta, so we can get an answer from the community

Comment: @Ankoganit, if the tag was letters, it would have been too obvious and too easy to be really a puzzle. Lateral-thinking is different, at least the way I understand it. Anyway, I wasn't even aware there was a tag letters at the time of posting. And "hidden message" does not really exclude the alphabet as a kind of message. For example, the Arecibo message does not contain words - it is a picture.

Comment: I believe that it should have been [pattern] and [poetry]. This bears a superficial resemblance to the "What is an ________ Word™?" puzzles, which are tagged [pattern].

Comment: @RahulParashar Thanks man. I just say a pattern. Its not everyday you use Xylophobia

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am guessing

> The Alphabet

Reasoning

> **A**re,**B**y,**C**ausing,**D**awn,**E**ruption,**F**rom,**G**rand,**H**ere,**I**n,**J**oy,**K**nock,**L**unatics,**M**ultiply,**N**ovember,**O**f,**P**icture,**Q**ueen,**R**ain,**S**tanding,**T**he,**U**pon,**V**ivid,**W**icked,**X**ylophia,**Y**ou,**Z**ebras

Answer (score -1):

> Alphabet-
> Upon looking at the puzzle it reminded me of the alphabet sentence "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".  I then looked for all the letters of the alphabet and saw that each word randomly began with each letter.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! It looks like this answer restates content that is already thoroughly expressed in another answer. In the future, please be sure to read through other answers on the site before adding your own. Thanks!